# how to send the 'auto.register.schemas':'false' in python producer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I'm recieveing the below error when try to produce to the kafka topic.

Error connecting to Kafka topic KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="User is denied operation Write on Subject: xxxxx-value (HTTP status code 403, SR code 40301)"}

i have written the producer in python langauage an all the configurations retrieve from the aws secret manager ex: bootstrap server url

now i'm getting the above error when producing the data

def schemaConfig():

```
# Define the value schema (or import from an avro file)
schema_str = """xxx
```

xxx
"""

```
# Parse the configuration.
config_parser = ConfigParser()


config_parser['default'] = {
    'bootstrap.servers': kafkaBootstrapServer,
    'security.protocol': kafkaSecurityProtocol,
    'sasl.mechanisms': kafkaSaslMechanism,
    'sasl.username': kafkaClusterApiKey,
    'sasl.password': kafkaClusterSecret,
    'session.timeout.ms': kafkaRequestTimeout
}

config_parser['producer'] = {
    'acks': 'all',
}

config_parser['avro'] = {
    'url': kafkaSchemaRegistryUrl,
    'basic.auth.user.info': kafkaSchemaRegisterApiKey+':'+kafkaSchemaSecret
}

# config_parser.read_file(args.config_file)
config = dict(config_parser["default"])
config.update(config_parser["producer"])

# Define schema registry client
schema_conf = dict(config_parser["avro"])
schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_conf)

# Create Avro Serializer
avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_registry_client, schema_str, user_to_dict)

# Create serializing producer
config.update(
    {"key.serializer": StringSerializer("utf_8"), "value.serializer": avro_serializer}
)
producer = SerializingProducer(config)

print("Inside the kafka call")

return producer
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi i was looking to how to add the auto.register.schemas':'false' in above python  script

Answer (score 1):

In the Python API, you set the `auto.register.schemas` config on the serializer.  So updating the `AvroSerialzier` configs to the following should do the trick:
UPDATE: you need to set those configs on the `AvroSerializer` itself and not the `SchemaRegistryClient` as I had shown before.  So updating to something like this should work:

```
serializer_configs = {
    'auto.register.schemas': False,
    'use.latest.version': True
}

avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_registry_client, schema_str, user_to_dict, serializer_configs)
```

Let me know if the update works for you. As a side note, you might want to check your credentials due to the `403` error

Comment: hi i added the changes now getting an error like this  raise ValueError("Unrecognized properties: {}"
ValueError: Unrecognized properties: auto.register.schemas, use.latest.version

Comment: What version are you using? Those configs should work with the 2.0.2 version (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#schemaregistry-avro-serializer)

Comment: i'm using fastavro 1.7.2 , confluent-kafka 2.0.2,  requests 2.28.2 and python 3.8                raise ValueError("Unrecognized properties: {}"
ValueError: Unrecognized properties: auto.register.schemas, use.latest.version

Comment: hmm ok, let me see if I can duplicate the issue - maybe there could be a bug or some other configuration I'm missing - I'll get back to you

Comment: @PumuduFernando I've updated my answer to reflect a working solution

Comment: it works fine after changing as above